# c++ multiple inheritance function merging

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have:

```
class XILightSource 
{
public:
    virtual XVec2 position() const = 0;
};

class XLightSprite : public XSprite, public XILightSource
{

};
```

The problem is that `XSprite` already has the same function `position`. How can i say to compiler, that i want to use `XSprite::position` function as an implementation of `XILightSource::position()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

override it and call XILightSource::position() :

```
class XLightSprite : public XSprite, public XILightSource
{
  public:
     XVec2 position() const { return  XSprite::position(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line:

```
class XLightSprite : public XSprite, public XILightSource
{
 public:
    using XSprite::position;
};
```

Comment: does not work. XLightSprite is still abstract. There solution could be used in case if XlightSourse::position was not pure i think

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need to do anything special.

By default, implementing a `XVec2 position() const` in `XLightSprite` will hide the `position()` of `XSprite` and act as an override of the virtual function defined in `XLightSource`.

If, however, you want to clarify that your intent is to override the function, you can add a using declaration

```
class XLightSprite : public XSprite, public XILightSource
{
 public:
    using XSprite::position;
    XVec2 position() const;
};
```

Please note, however, that if the position() from XSprite is also a  virtual function on the same format, the new implementation will also act as an override of the position in XSprite.

Answer (score 0):

If `class XSprite` already has that function then the best way is to make `XSprite` a child of `XILightSource` (since it's abstract). The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to rely on multiple inheritance unnecessarily. i.e.

```
class XILightSource 
{
public:
  virtual XVec2 position() const = 0;
};

class XSprite : public XILightSource
{
public:
  virtual XVec2 position() const { ... }
};

class XLightSprite : public XSprite
{
};
```